# How to combine independent probability distributions?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, random-variable

I have 3 probability distributions derived from three random variables, where the distributions and the variables are independent. How do I combine all 3 distributions, either via direct aggregation of the distributions or through a mixture of distributions with equal weights for all the 3 distributions.

For reference, this is how my 3 distributions are in Python:

```
prob1, _ = np.histogram(valsA, bins=1024, density=True)
prob2, _ = np.histogram(valsB, bins=1024, density=True)
prob3, _ = np.histogram(valsC, bins=1024, density=True)
```

I'm a novice to statistics, so any advice would be valuable.
Also, there is no other way to deal with the 3 variables, I need to retrieve their distributions and then aggregate it.

Comment: Combine in what sense? Are you after a joint density, or are you trying to get the density of the sum, (or product etc) of the underlying random variables?

Comment: I am trying to get the joint probability density function

Answer (score 2):

If all you have to work from are those histograms as density estimates (presumably scaled to integrate to 1) you could estimate the joint density from their product.

$\hat{f}_{X,Y,Z}=\hat{f_X}\,\hat{f_{Y}}\,\hat{f_{Z}}$

Comment: Would the result joint density function also integrate to 1 ?

Comment: $\int\int\int \hat{f}_{X,Y,Z} \,dx \, dy \, dz $ $=$ $\int\int\int \hat{f_X}\,\hat{f_{Y}}\,\hat{f_{Z}} \,dx\, dy\, dz $ $=$ $ \int\hat{f_X}\,dx \cdot\int\hat{f_{Y}}\,dy\cdot\int \,\hat{f_{Z}} \, dz $ $=$ $ 1 \times 1\times 1$

Comment: Got it, thank you !

Comment: You may like to consider why each step is justified